# How to average between rows in a Dataframe to fillup missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, nan

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
Date
2016-11-21    26.292355
2016-11-22    26.308828
2016-11-23    26.174692
2016-11-24          NaN
2016-11-25    26.306471
2016-11-26          NaN
2016-11-27          NaN
2016-11-28    26.254705
2016-11-29    26.228815
2016-11-30    26.007618
2016-12-01    25.765236
2016-12-02    25.861721
2016-12-03          NaN
2016-12-04          NaN
2016-12-05    25.675812
2016-12-06    25.873482
2016-12-07    26.127634
2016-12-08    26.384132
2016-12-09    26.814764
Name: Close, dtype: object
```

I want to fill up these missing `NaN` values with the average value from the previous row and the next row.

The resulting dataframe would be:

```
Date
2016-11-21    26.292355
2016-11-22    26.308828
2016-11-23    26.174692
2016-11-24    26.240581  # Averaged value from previous and next row
2016-11-25    26.306471
2016-11-26    26.280588  # Averaged value from previous and next row
2016-11-27    26.280588  # Averaged value from previous and next row
2016-11-28    26.254705
2016-11-29    26.228815
2016-11-30    26.007618
2016-12-01    25.765236
2016-12-02    25.861721
2016-12-03    25.768766  # Averaged value from previous and next row
2016-12-04    25.768766  # Averaged value from previous and next row
2016-12-05    25.675812
2016-12-06    25.873482
2016-12-07    26.127634
2016-12-08    26.384132
2016-12-09    26.814764
Name: Close, dtype: object
```

How would I do this in python?

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Series.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
>>> sr.interpolate(method='linear')
Date
2016-11-21    26.292355
2016-11-22    26.308828
2016-11-23    26.174692
2016-11-24    26.240581
2016-11-25    26.306471
2016-11-26    26.289216
2016-11-27    26.271960
2016-11-28    26.254705
2016-11-29    26.228815
2016-11-30    26.007618
2016-12-01    25.765236
2016-12-02    25.861721
2016-12-03    25.799751
2016-12-04    25.737782
2016-12-05    25.675812
2016-12-06    25.873482
2016-12-07    26.127634
2016-12-08    26.384132
2016-12-09    26.814764
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```